# sendMessage_Click will not create an event

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I am working on a contact page using asp. in the form I created the text boxes fine for Name, Address, Email etc etc.(Page displays fine up to this point)
When I create the button code- it will not create an event or rather the test_form.aspx.cs

Here is my code. I was following a youTube channel to get this to work.

```html
<form runat="server"> 
<asp:TextBox ID="Name" placeholder="Name:" runat="server" /> <br /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="SenderEmail" placeholder="Email:" runat="server" /> <br /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="SenderPhone" placeholder="Phone:" runat="server" /> <br /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="Subject" placeholder="Subject:" runat="server" /> <br /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="Message" placeholder="Message:" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="100" /> <br /> 
<asp:Button ID="Send" Text="Send Message" runat="server" OnClick="sendMessage_Click" /> <br />

</form>
```

ANd I get this error code when I run the page

```
Line 163:                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Message" placeholder="Message:" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="100" />
Line 164:                                            <br />
Line 165:                                            <asp:Button ID="Send" Text="Send Message" runat="server" OnClick="sendMessage_Click" />
Line 166:                                            <br />
Line 167:
```

Comment: c:\Users\mcs\source\repos\Joe Libeu\Joe Libeu\Test Form.aspx(165,59): error This is the error message I receive.CS1061: 'ASP.test_form_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'sendMessage_Click' and no extension method 'sendMessage_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.test_form_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add more information. Prefix the line with "`>`" to quote error messages such as this.

Comment: Here is my code                    <form runat="server">  <asp:TextBox ID="Name" placeholder="Name:" runat="server" /> <br /> <asp:TextBox ID="SenderEmail" placeholder="Email:" runat="server" /> <br /> <asp:TextBox ID="SenderPhone" placeholder="Phone:" runat="server" /> <br/> <asp:TextBox ID="Subject" placeholder="Subject:" runat="server" /> <br /> <asp:TextBox ID="Message" placeholder="Message:" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="100" /> <br />  <asp:Button ID="Send" Text="Send Message" runat="server" OnClick="sendMessage_Click"  />  <br /> </form>

Comment: please: [edit] your question; put the code and the error in the question. not in the comments. its hard to read.

Comment: @mcsmelinda: Your last comment duplicates the code in the question, which I fenced in my edit so that it appears correctly. It's not needed in the comments; you may delete that comment. Instead, please add the C# code to the question. It's missing a visible method called `sendMessage_Click`, possibly just because of a difference in the case of the name.